# What is the limit $\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{1}{(3-x)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, fractions

> Why does the limit of $\frac{1}{(3-x)^2}$ become infinity as $x\to 3$?

When I simplify the expression I get 
$$
\frac{1}{(9-6x+x^2)},
$$ 
which would give the limit $-\frac{1}{18}$ as $x$ approaches $3$. I don't understand what goes wrong.

Comment: $x^2-6x+9$ is $0$ when $x=3$.  But why bother expanding?  It is already clear that $(x-3)^2$ is $0$ when$x=3$.

Comment: If you insert $3$ then $9-6x+x^2$ becomes $9-18+9=0$.

Comment: You seem to have computed $9-6x+x^2$ at $x=3$ as $9-6\cdot 3\color{red}{-}3^2$, which is of course wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be considering what the fraction equates to at *x*=3, but rather what happens when *x* approaches 3 from the left and right side. What I mean by this is, consider *x* coming in from the negative and positive sides of the horizontal axis.

First, notice when x = 3, the fraction becomes 1/0, not -1/18. So let us consider the limit of the fraction as x approaches 3.

When x approaches 3 from the negative side, we can get very close to 3, say 2.999999.

Similarly, if we come in from the positive side, we can get close to 3, say 3.000000001.

When you plug these numbers back into the equation, you can see that the fraction becomes very ***positively large*** in ***both cases***.

However it can get larger if we extended the decimals, therefore the Limit as x approaches 3 of the fraction becomes positive infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the term is positive all the time, we can't possibly have negative limit.

Notice that as $x \to 3$, $(x-3)^2$ approaches $0$.

Comment: How can i know that the function approach positive infinity and not negative then? I understand it is because (x - 3) is squared but is there a mathematical way of showing it?

Comment: try to show that whenever you pick a positive $M$, you are able to find a neighborhood of $3$ such that every function value there is more than $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Small numbers have large reciprocals, and $x-3$ gets small as $x \rightarrow 3.$ 
The square of $x-3$ is positive (and small) for $x$ near 3, so its reciprocal is positive (and large). The value of $\frac{1}{x-3}$ tends to plus infinity from either side of 3, so the limit does not exist (or, is $+\infty,$ depending on the conventions in place).

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x-3 \to 0$, then

$$\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{1}{(3-x)^2}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{y^2}$$

then note that for any $M>0$

$$\frac{1}{y^2}\ge M \implies |y|\le \frac1{\sqrt M}$$

therefore by definition the limit is $\infty$.